# Thread 1: Signal SIGABRT (Xcode 8.3.1)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode8, sigabrt

I updated to Xcode 8.3.1 and I keep getting this error. I created a blank project, added the OneSignal pod file, opened the .xcworkspace file and I get this error when I run it (no other edits to the project). I cleaned the build folder, restarted Xcode as well as the mac but I can't fix it.

I know this error is usually if you have an outlet that isn't connected to something etc. but that's not the case here as this is a blank project.

Comment: Did you try to clean the project/update the pod? Did you make sure that the pod is compatible with the version of Swift that your project is set to?

Comment: How did you add the pod file?

Comment: Yeah I did that @the4kman

Comment: "Pod init" then edit the pod file, then "pod install" @Llg

Comment: Was Xcode closed when you did that? Please read this https://www.raywenderlich.com/97014/use-cocoapods-with-swift

Comment: Yes it was. I've used pods many times with previous projects and it worked fine, just now with Xcode 8.3.1 (updated from 8.2) isn't working @Llg